# Building the shortest route through all points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, polyline-creation, shortest-path, travelling-salesman

How to build the shortest route through all selected points, starting from a given point? Which plugin to use?

There is a point layer and a linear layer for all routes between points.

[image]

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 13):

What you're looking for is called ["Travelling salesman problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

Let's assume there is a point and a line layers, see the image below.

[image: input]

There are several approaches available:

**Approach 1 :** [qgis-grass-plugin](/questions/tagged/qgis-grass-plugin)

[`v.net.salesman`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass80/manuals/v.net.salesman.html)

> Creates a cycle connecting given nodes (Traveling salesman problem).
> Note that TSP is NP-hard, heuristic algorithm is used by this module
> and created cycle may be sub optimal

This geoalgorithm takes a layer nd a point layer as an input.

[image: result1]

**Approach 2 :** [pyqgis](/questions/tagged/pyqgis)

Find a corresponding Python package and install it via OSGeo4W Shell. In this example I used the [`tsp_solver2`](https://pypi.org/project/tsp-solver2/) library.

⚠️ The last update to this package was done in July 2020.

In the below script, you do not need a line layer.

```py
# imports
import geopandas as gpd
from qgis import processing
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from tsp_solver.greedy import solve_tsp

# referring to a layer by its name
point_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("YOUR_LAYER_NAME")[0]

# creating a GeoDataFrame from a QgsVectorLayer
gdf = gpd.read_file(point_layer.source())

# calculating a distance matrix
dm = gdf.geometry.apply(lambda g: gdf.distance(g))
# convertign a distance matrix to a NumPy array
dm = dm.to_numpy()

# applying the TSP solver
min_path = solve_tsp(dm, endpoints=(0,2)) # change endpoints ids accordingly
# if one wants an enclosing line, please modify the above list
# min_path.insert(len(min_path), min_path[0])

# converting previous output to a real path
params = {
    'INPUT' : point_layer,
    'CLOSE_PATH' : False,
    'GROUP_EXPRESSION' : '',
    'NATURAL_SORT' : True,
    'ORDER_EXPRESSION' : f"array_get(min_path, $id)",
    'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
    }
result = processing.run("native:pointstopath", params)

# adding result to the project
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(result['OUTPUT'])
```

or if one prefers pure PyQGIS:

```py
# imports
import geopandas as gpd
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer, QgsGeometry, QgsPoint, QgsFeature
from tsp_solver.greedy import solve_tsp

# referring to a layer by its name
point_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("YOUR_LAYER_NAME")[0]

# creating a GeoDataFrame from a QgsVectorLayer
gdf = gpd.read_file(point_layer.source())

# calculating a distance matrix
dm = gdf.geometry.apply(lambda g: gdf.distance(g))
# convertign a distance matrix to a NumPy array
dm = dm.to_numpy()

# applying the TSP solver
min_path = solve_tsp(dm, endpoints=(0, 2))  # change endpoints ids accordingly
# if one wants an enclosing line, please modify the above list
# min_path.insert(len(min_path), min_path[0])

# creating a PolyLine geometry
min_path_geom = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(
    [QgsPoint(point_layer.getFeature(node).geometry().asPoint()) for node in min_path])

# creating an empty vector layer
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(f"LineString?query=SELECT ST_GeomFromText('{min_path_geom.asWkt()}',"
                        f"{point_layer.crs().postgisSrid()})", "vlayer", "virtual")

# adding output layer to the canvas
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

[image: result3]

**Approach 3 :** [qgis-plugins](/questions/tagged/qgis-plugins)

The [ORS Tools](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ORStools/) Plugin

> openrouteservice routing, isochrones and matrix calculations for QGIS

An API Key is required. It has a Fix Start.

<s>**Approach 4 :**</s> [qgis-plugins](/questions/tagged/qgis-plugins)

The [MTSP Routing](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mtsp_routing_qgis/) Plugin

##### [image] 
Either plugin or Python library currently is not available.

It requires additional installation in QGIS of the Python package [mtsp-routing](https://pypi.org/project/mtsp-routing/).

---

**References:**

- [YouTube | Traveling Salesman Problem Visualization](https://youtu.be/SC5CX8drAtU)
- [wiki.gis.com | Travelling salesman problem](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Travelling_salesman_problem)
- [Why Travelling Salesman Problem plugin is not working in QGIS 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/456456/why-travelling-salesman-problem-plugin-is-not-working-in-qgis-3)

Comment: Just by curiosity, between GRASS and MTSP, what are the lengths and who is the shortest ?

Comment: MTSP Routing : 2.30191e+07, GRASS : 2.020225e+07

Comment: Thanks, GRASS win ! And to answer the OP question, choose a point and "delete" the longest of the two lines from this point to have the shortest route through all selected points.

Comment: I get an error during installation MTSP Routing Plugin

Comment: install through the Plugins tab

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'routing'

Comment: may need to be installed through the python console first

Comment: @Taras  can i write to you in ukrainian?
possibly to another address
I'm from Ukraine :)

Comment: yes, please text me in ukrainian

Answer (score 1):

You can also use networkx together with pyqgis:

```py
from itertools import combinations
import networkx as nx
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("building")[0]

all_features = [f for f in layer.getSelectedFeatures()] #List all selected features

edgelist = [] #A list to hold all pairs of features and the distance between them: [(feature1, feature2, distance), (feature2, feature3, distance) ...]
for featurepair in combinations(all_features, 2):
    f1, f2 = featurepair
    edgelist.append((f1.id(), f2.id(), f1.geometry().distance(f2.geometry())))
    
#print(edgelist[0])
#(37780, 37859, 4570.112717970702) "(id of feature 1, id of feature 2, distance between 1 and 2)

#Create a graph from the list of edges
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from(edgelist)
tsp = nx.approximation.traveling_salesman_problem
route = tsp(G=G, nodes=G.nodes, weight="weight")
#The best route is:
#[37780, 41930, 41928, 41926, 41923, 41929, 41933, 41931, 41932, 41936, 37955, 42667, 42664, 42661, 42653, 41918, 41917, 42848, 42850, 42853, 42043, 42042, 42046, 41916, 41915, 42132, 41925, 41938, 37859, 37780]

#Create a line layer of the route
all_geometries = {f.id():f.geometry().asPoint() for f in all_features} #Dictionary of each features id and its geometry
vl = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs={}&index=yes&field=id:integer".format(layer.crs().authid()), 
"shortest_path", "memory")
provider = vl.dataProvider()
for featurepair in zip(route, route[1:]):
    f1, f2 = featurepair
    new_feature = QgsFeature(fields)
    line_geometry = QgsGeometry(QgsLineString([all_geometries[f1],all_geometries[f2]]))
    new_feature.setGeometry(line_geometry)
    provider.addFeature(new_feature)
    
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

[image]

Comment: ah ... how could I forget about this great package `networkx`. Thank you so much for such a sophisticated solution!

Comment: And you also do know how to loop over each features pair with PyQGIS https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/471792/looping-every-features-pair-with-pyqgis @_@

Comment: That is amazing! Fascinates me so much!